# How to disable DNS client caching on debian stretch?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, dns, raspbian

Im suspecting DNS caching to be the cause of some intermittent woes. Is it possible to disabled dns caching from the dns client side on debian stretch (raspbian)?

Comment: The default resolver on Debian stretch (the libc stub resolver) does not do any caching. I recommend checking facts via `tcpdump` first: do DNS query packets leave your machine on each resolution operation or not? Are the answers always as expected?

Comment: thank you. ill try that